# Need help getting user input of min and max

Tags: java, max, min

Hello need help with this program where I need it to ask the user for 2 integers (Y and Z which is where i get my error) where one will be a min and the other a max and i don't understand why it doesn't run properly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sampleMethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printYikes();
        int x = 12;

        x = getAnInt("Please enter an integer min and a max seperated by a space: ",y, z);

        System.out.println("\nThat was a valid Number.");
        System.out.println("You entered " + x + "!");
        System.out.println( "x is " + x );
        x = doubleMyNumber(x);
        System.out.println( "x is " + x );
        x = tripleMyNumber(x);
        System.out.println( "x is " + x );

    }



    static void printYikes() {
        System.out.println("Yikes");
    }

    static int doubleMyNumber(int a) {
        int b = a * 2;
        return b;
    }

    static int tripleMyNumber(int a) {
        int c = a * 3;
        boolean odd = isOddOrEven(c);
        if (odd) {
            System.out.println("Number is Odd!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number is Even!!");
        }
        return c;
    }

    static boolean isOddOrEven (int d) {
        boolean isOdd = false;
        if (d % 2 == 0) {
            isOdd = false;
        } else {
            isOdd = true;
        }
        return isOdd;
    }

    static int getAnInt(String prompt, int min, int max) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean numberError = false;
        int enteredNumber = 0;
        String enteredString = "";
        do {
            try {
                System.out.print(prompt);
                enteredString = keyboard.nextLine();  //Read into a string
                enteredNumber = Integer.parseInt(enteredString.trim());  //then cast as a integer
                numberError = false;  //if we haven't bailed out, then the number must be valid.
                if (enteredNumber < min || enteredNumber > max) {
                    numberError = true;
                    System.out.println("Your entry: \"" + enteredNumber + "\" is out of range...Please try again");
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Your entry: \"" + enteredString + "\" is invalid...Please try again");
                numberError = true;  //Uh-Oh...We have a problem.
            }
        } while (numberError == true );  //Keep asking the user until the correct number is entered.

        return enteredNumber;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared y,z;

Write this after `int x = 12` :

```
int y,z;
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `int getAnInt(String prompt, int min, int max)` expects three parameters:

- `prompt` - the string to ask the user.
- `min` - the minimum value you'll accept.
- `max` - the maximum value you'll accept.

It returns an `int` that is guaranteed to be between `min` and `max`. That's what the function does. Nothing more; nothing less. You can't use it to ask for two numbers separated by a space.

It sounds like you used to have an existing program that asked for a single value, with arbitrary `min` and `max` values (0 and 100? 1 and 10?).

Now you want to change this program to *first* ask for the minimum and maximum values, and *then* do the previous processing. You need to ask the user for two more numbers - and those numbers need a `min` and `max` specified too!

Replace `int x = 12;` with:

```
    int min, max, x;
    min = getAnInt("Please enter an integer minimum between 0 and 1000000: ", 0, 1000000);
    max = getAnInt("Please enter an integer maximum larger than minimum and less than 1000001: ", min, 1000001);

    x = getAnInt("Please enter an integer x between minimum and maximum: ",min, max);
```